# Adding to a String in Swift 4

Tags: swift, string, swift4

I was wondering the best way to add to a `String` in Swift 4. Did Apple create a better way than `stringName.characters.append(“hi”)`

Edit: Noted below which I never knew you used to be able to use a String.append(). I was trying to get at the fact that in Swift 4 you don't have to use `.characters` anymore. I was trying to help out new people to swift 4 by making a question that they might ask so that they can save time by not using `.characters` after a String variable.

Comment: It was always possible to use `string.append(anotherString)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can invoke [`append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641225-append) directly on the `String` instance:

```
var stringName = ""
stringName.append("hi")
print(stringName) // hi
stringName.append(" John")
print(stringName) // hi John
```

Likewise, you can use the [`+=` operator of `String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2429829) for the concatenation

```
var stringName = ""
stringName += "hi"
print(stringName) // hi
stringName += " John"
print(stringName) // hi John
```

---

For the curious one, the implementation of both of these approaches make use of the same backend (/core) `append(...)` call. Quoting [swift/stdlib/public/core/String.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift):

> ```
> extension String {
>
>   // ...
>
>   public mutating func append(_ other: String) {
>     _core.append(other._core)
>   }
>
>   // ...
> }
>
> extension String {
>
>   // ...
>
>   public static func += (lhs: inout String, rhs: String) {
>     if lhs.isEmpty {
>       lhs = rhs
>     }
>     else {
>       lhs._core.append(rhs._core)
>     }
>   }
>
>   // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I do know the answer(I was at WWDC), but trying to get my rep up with questions and stuff. And figured someone will be asking.

Comment: @the_kaseys if you have a question that you already know the answer to, and believe this could be a valuable Q&A for other visitors here at SO (possibly not trivial questions that are already well covered by the language reference), you [may ask and answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Answering other's questions is very much more common though, and can also be good practice for the answerer (I've learnt a lot in the process of writing my SO answers).

Comment: Oh dang my bad. I appreciate you letting me know! I just got started with SO.

Comment: @the_kaseys no worries, and welcome to SO! Make sure to take your time reading through the [_Asking_ section in the _SO Help Center_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) (probably most importantly the subsections coverings [_MVCE_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [_How do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) subsections), which contains lots of valuable information for SO newcomers, especially if you want to post questions of your own!

Answer (score 0):

According to Swift 4 Documentation,
String values can be added together (or concatenated) with the addition operator (+) to create a new String value:

```
let string1 = "hello"
let string2 = " there"
var welcome = string1 + string2
// welcome now equals "hello there"
```

You can also append a String value to an existing String variable with the addition assignment operator (+=):

```
var instruction = "look over"
instruction += string2
// instruction now equals "look over there"
```

You can append a Character value to a String variable with the String type’s append() method:

```
let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
welcome.append(exclamationMark)
// welcome now equals "hello there!"
```